# Bigquery: Get schema for query without actually running it

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to get schema of bigquery query without actual running it? (I've tried DryRun, but it returns only statistics but no actual schema)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a good way to get a schema without running a query. There *is* however, a hacky way to do it.

You can create a View using the query that you want to check out. The view will then have a schema that would result from running that query. You can then delete the view when you're done.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. This way has really big limitations, but seems to work much faster as actual execution.
As for the limitations - 
1. no nested fields are supported
2. if you select from table with nested fields (smth like cell.volume_count as cell) it will give you an error though actual query execution don't.

Answer (score 3):

The schema is contained inside the query response body both in normal and dry runs, when they are successful [[ref](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#response-body)], and that's probably how views get their schema without running the query.

However, if you want to retrieve it with [bigquery's python library](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html), you have to access the [QueryJob](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google-cloud-bigquery-job-queryjob) class "internal" attributes and methods like follows, since no "public" ones are provided...

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
# bigquery.__version__ == '1.9.0'

client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(dry_run=True)

query_job = client.query(
    query="SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`",
    job_config=job_config,
)

# Solution 1
schema = query_job._properties['statistics']['query']['schema']

# Solution 2 
job_stats = query_job._job_statistics()
schema = job_stats['schema']
```

It took me a while to figure this out. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ok with getting the schema with API, you'll need to invoke `Tables: get` method to get table's schema.

For natality table from samples dataset in publicdata project, the request would be

```
   GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/publicdata/datasets/samples/tables/natality?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and the associated response would be

```
{ 
 "kind": "bigquery#table",
 "etag": "\"nwg3tKAm7RiC5vqWthFIuCNSGxs/MTQ0MDYyNTMzMDYwNA\"",
 "id": "publicdata:samples.natality",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/publicdata/datasets/samples/tables/natality",
 "tableReference": {
  "projectId": "publicdata",
  "datasetId": "samples",
  "tableId": "natality"
 },
 "description": "This table describes all United States births registered in the 50 States, the District of Columbia, and New York City from 1969 to 2008. The Centers for Disease Control (CDC) and Prevention's National Center for Health Statistics (NCHS) receives this data as electronic files, prepared from individual records processed by each registration area, through the Vital Statistics Cooperative Program. \n\nYou can access the CDC's data at: http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/Vitalstatsonline.htm",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "source_year",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "Four-digit year of the birth. Example: 1975."
   },
   {
    "name": "year",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Four-digit year of the birth. Example: 1975."
   },
   {
    "name": "month",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Month index of the date of birth, where 1=January."
   },
   {
    "name": "day",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Day of birth, starting from 1."
   },
   {
    "name": "wday",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Day of the week, where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday."
   },
   {
    "name": "state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The two character postal code for the state. Entries after 2004 do not include this value."
   },
   {
    "name": "is_male",
    "type": "BOOLEAN",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "description": "TRUE if the child is male, FALSE if female."
   },
   {
    "name": "child_race",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The race of the child. One of the following numbers:\n\n1 - White\n2 - Black\n3 - American Indian\n4 - Chinese\n5 - Japanese\n6 - Hawaiian\n7 - Filipino\n9 - Unknown/Other\n18 - Asian Indian\n28 - Korean\n39 - Samoan\n48 - Vietnamese"
   },
   {
    "name": "weight_pounds",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Weight of the child, in pounds."
   },
   {
    "name": "plurality",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "How many children were born as a result of this pregnancy. twins=2, triplets=3, and so on."
   },
   {
    "name": "apgar_1min",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Apgar scores measure the health of a newborn child on a scale from 0-10. Value after 1 minute. Available from 1978-2002."
   },
   {
    "name": "apgar_5min",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Apgar scores measure the health of a newborn child on a scale from 0-10. Value after 5 minutes. Available from 1978-2002."
   },
   {
    "name": "mother_residence_state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The two-letter postal code of the mother's state of residence when the child was born."
   },
   {
    "name": "mother_race",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Race of the mother. Same values as child_race."
   },
   {
    "name": "mother_age",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Reported age of the mother when giving birth."
   },
   {
    "name": "gestation_weeks",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The number of weeks of the pregnancy."
   },
   {
    "name": "lmp",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Date of the last menstrual period in the format MMDDYYYY. Unknown values are recorded as \"99\" or \"9999\"."
   },
   {
    "name": "mother_married",
    "type": "BOOLEAN",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "True if the mother was married when she gave birth."
   },
   {
    "name": "mother_birth_state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The two-letter postal code of the mother's birth state."
   },
   {
    "name": "cigarette_use",
    "type": "BOOLEAN",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "True if the mother smoked cigarettes. Available starting 2003."
   },
   {
    "name": "cigarettes_per_day",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of cigarettes smoked by the mother per day. Available starting 2003."
   },
   {
    "name": "alcohol_use",
    "type": "BOOLEAN",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "True if the mother used alcohol. Available starting 1989."
   },
   {
    "name": "drinks_per_week",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of drinks per week consumed by the mother. Available starting 1989."
   },
   {
    "name": "weight_gain_pounds",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of pounds gained by the mother during pregnancy."
   },
   {
    "name": "born_alive_alive",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of children previously born to the mother who are now living."
   },
   {
    "name": "born_alive_dead",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of children previously born to the mother who are now dead."
   },
   {
    "name": "born_dead",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Number of children who were born dead (i.e. miscarriages)"
   },
   {
    "name": "ever_born",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Total number of children to whom the woman has ever given birth (includes the current birth)."
   },
   {
    "name": "father_race",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Race of the father. Same values as child_race."
   },
   {
    "name": "father_age",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Age of the father when the child was born."
   },
   {
    "name": "record_weight",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "1 or 2, where 1 is a row from a full-reporting area, and 2 is a row from a 50% sample area."
   }
  ]
 },
 "numBytes": "23562717384",
 "numRows": "137826763",
 "creationTime": "1335916045005",
 "lastModifiedTime": "1440625330604",
 "type": "TABLE",
 "location": "US"
}
```

If the command-line is more convenient, you can run bq command with the following parameters to get table's schema:

`bq show publicdata:samples.natality`

The output looks like this:

```
Table publicdata:samples.natality

   Last modified                  Schema                 Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration
 ----------------- ------------------------------------ ------------ ------------- ------------
  27 Aug 00:42:10   |- source_year: integer (required)   137826763    23562717384
                    |- year: integer
                    |- month: integer
                    |- day: integer
                    |- wday: integer
                    |- state: string
                    |- is_male: boolean (required)
                    |- child_race: integer
                    |- weight_pounds: float
                    |- plurality: integer
                    |- apgar_1min: integer
                    |- apgar_5min: integer
                    |- mother_residence_state: string
                    |- mother_race: integer
                    |- mother_age: integer
                    |- gestation_weeks: integer
                    |- lmp: string
                    |- mother_married: boolean
                    |- mother_birth_state: string
                    |- cigarette_use: boolean
                    |- cigarettes_per_day: integer
                    |- alcohol_use: boolean
                    |- drinks_per_week: integer
                    |- weight_gain_pounds: integer
                    |- born_alive_alive: integer
                    |- born_alive_dead: integer
                    |- born_dead: integer
                    |- ever_born: integer
                    |- father_race: integer
                    |- father_age: integer
                    |- record_weight: integer
```

Comment: this is only for tables, I think the question is regarding queries.